# Easy Matrices Problem

Tags: matrices

> Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{array}\right)$.

Find $X$ if $AB-2X = \left(\begin{array}{rr} 1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.

Any hints or help would be much appreciated! I'm really not sure how to go about solving this after I've found the product of A and B..

Comment: $X=(1/2)(AB{\rm\ minus\ that\ other\ matrix})$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, do you know how to calculate $AB$? The calculation is similar if they are non-square, all you need is for the columns of $A$ and rows of $B$ to be equal.

Comment: Ah, so the real problem is that you don't know how to multiply matrices! Now we're getting somewhere. But surely you have a textbook that explains this?

Comment: It does but obviously not in clear enough terms for me at least..

Comment: I wonder about these "easy" titled questions: if they're easy then why to ask them? Or perhaps they're trying to lure us to answer...

Comment: @DonAntonio easy because they most likely are for others but not for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that two matrices  $M:=(a_{ij}),M':=(b_{kl})$ are (by definition) equal to  each other precisely when the $(l,m)$ entry of M is equal to the same $(l,m)$ of M. From this, it follows that $A,B$ must have the same dimensions, i.e., they must have the same number of rows and columns respectively. Notice that the product AB is a $2\times 2$-matrix, so that $2X$ must also be a $2\times2$ matrix, and the $(l,m)$-entry of $X$ must equal the corresponding $(l,m)$-entry of $
AB$. Now, after multiplying $AB$ this should give you the answer--up to a factor of 2.

To add another definition of multiplication to the one by Gerry Myerson, the product of matrices  AB is , in a sense, a product  of the rows of A by the colums of B. We multiply the 1st row of A by the first column of B, then the first row by the second column, ..., then the 1st row of A by the last column of B, and we repeat this for each row of A, i.e.,  we multiply the j-th row of B by the 1st, 2nd,.., last column of B, and in each product we get a number. The product of the i-th row of A by the j-th column of B will be the $(i,j)$-entry of the product matrix  $AB$. As Gerry said, the product of a row by a column is done term-by-term, i.e., you multiply the first term of a row by the first term of a column, the second by the second, ..., the last term  of a row by the last term of a column, and then we add all the result (NOTE that by first term of a row, I mean leftmost term, and by first term of a column we mean the top, "northern-most"term.

O.K, say we have multiplied $AB$, to get a $2\times 2$ matrix C. Now we have to find a $2\times 2$ matrix X that satisfies the condition $AB-2X=$ the right-hand side matrix. Let's write out  $C$ first:

$C=\left(\begin{array}{rr} c_{11} & c
_{12}  \\ c_{21} & c_{22}  \end{array}\right)$

Now let's write the matrix X
$X=\left(\begin{array}{rr} x_{11} & x
_{12}  \\ x_{21} & x_{22}  \end{array}\right)$

Remember that the matrix  2X is equal to the matrix  X with each  entry multiplied by 2, so that we get:

$2X=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 2x_{11} & 2x
_{12}  \\ 2x_{21} & 2x_{22}  \end{array}\right)$.

We now need to find the matrix AB-2X and set it equal to the matrix on the right, let's call it $D$. Then the matrix AB-2X must be equal, entry-by-entry to $D$.

Comment: Yes, but OP doesn't know how to multiply matrices.

Comment: Ah, I see, let me add the definition of product as an edit. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @FBD: Thanks for explaining that. So now I've found the product of AB, do I then subtract it from both sides. So I'm left with -2x= the two matrixes? And then multiply both sides by -1/2?

Comment: @jaykirby: no problem. Set the product AB to be equal to a $2x2$ matrix X . Notice that the matrix 2X equals the matrix X with each entry multiplied by 2. Then we have an equation where AB=2X. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @FBD: I'm kind of confused by what you just wrote, much more of a visual learner. If its not too much trouble could you show me what you mean using numbers?

Comment: @jaykirby: I will write an edit to explain; pleaase give me a few minutes to complete it.

Comment: @jaykirby: please let me know if the bottom paragraph I just wrote answers your questions.

Comment: @FBD: Thanks, is there an easier way to solve it? If we have the matrix which is AB - 2x = the other given matrix. Can't we just subtract AB from both sides and then multiply both sides by -1/2?

Comment: @jaykirby: exactly; I actually made a mistake, I was trying to solve AB=2X, but , as you correctly pointed out, we need to find AB-2X and set that equal to the other matrix. Let me edit what I wrote; sorry.

Comment: you get an equation (5,-1,1,1)-2X=(1,2,-2,1). You can pass (1,2,-2,1) to the other side, find the difference , say, F, and then set F=2X , then F and X must be equal to each other entry-by-entry.

Comment: @FBD: Understood. Just to double check is AB (5,-1,1,1) or (5,-1,1,3)?

Comment: jaykirby: I got (5,-1,1,1); last entry is:$ 2(1)+(1)(-1)+(-1)(0)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about dot products? The entry in row $i$, column $j$ of the product is the dot product of row $i$ of $A$ with column $j$ of $B$.

Comment: Nope..first I've heard of dot products

Comment: OK: the dot product of $(a,b,c,\dots)$ and $(r,s,t,\dots)$ is $ar+bs+ct+\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem statment

$$
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{AB} -2\mathbf{X} &= \mathbf{C} \\
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 2 & -1 \\
 2 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% B
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% X
 -2 \mathbf{X}
%
&=
% C
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\\ 
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% X
 -2 \mathbf{X}
%
&=
% C
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

### Solution

Rearrange:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% X
-
% C
\left[
\begin{array}{rc}
 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
 2 \mathbf{X}
$$

Subtract:
$$
2\mathbf{X} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 0 & -3 \\
 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Conclude:
$$
\mathbf{X} = 
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 0 & -3 \\
 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

**Primer on matrix multiplication**

Compute the matrix product $\mathbf{AB}$

Look at the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as a collection of *row* vectors
$$
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 2 & -1 \\\hline
 2 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 v^{T}_{1} \\\hline
 v^{T}_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Look at the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ as a collection of *column* vectors
$$
% B
\left[
\begin{array}{c|r}
 1 &  1 \\
 1 & -1 \\
 2 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 w_{1} & w_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The matrix product is constructed using
$$
\mathbf{AB} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 v^{T}_{1} \\\hline
 v^{T}_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 w_{1} & w_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 v^{T}_{1} w_{1} & v^{T}_{1} w_{2} \\
 v^{T}_{2} w_{1} & v^{T}_{2} w_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

For example
$$
v^{T}_{1} w_{1} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1  & 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 2
\end{array}
\right]
%
= 1 + 2 - 2
%
= 1
$$