# How to expand and simplify this expression?

Tags: matrices

If asked to expand and simplify the following expression (assuming matrix operations are all defined): $A(A+B)-B(A-B)$?

Is the answer simply $A^2 + AB -BA +B^2$. And then simplified, its $A^2 + B^2$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Surely you are aware that AB-BA is not *always* zero when A and B are matrices, aren't you?

Comment: @Did nope I didn't know that!

Comment: Are $A,B$ just simply real numbers?

Comment: Then instead of asking random questions about matrices on MSE, you might try to study the basics of the theory in any text you might have. Instead, it is difficult to fathom the kind of answers would help you.

Comment: As witnessed by [this MSE page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/464089/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that since [matrix multiplication isn't always commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#All_matrices), we don't know for certain whether or not $AB=BA$ (indeed, $A$ and $B$ likely don't commute). Hence, the best we can do is to simplify it as:
$$
A^2 + AB -BA +B^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why it isnt commutative?

Comment: @ jaykirby: There're many counter examples.

Comment: There's no much explanation to do in this case, @jaykirby" just take several examples even of $\,2\times 2\;$ matrices and get convinced you don't always have commutativity. In fact, in some way,  and unless one of your matrices is a scalar one then **for sure** there's at least one matrix which doesn't commute with it.

Comment: Not sure the OP knows what *commutativity* is...

Comment: For example: rotating 90° and then reflecting has not the same result as reflecting and then rotating 90°.

Comment: **Hint:** Let 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and
$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Now compute $AB$ and compute $BA$ and compare the results.